# compare dates in a conditionalPanel using R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am using `conditionalPanel` in the `ui.R` file. I want to compare if the given date in a `selectinput` before or after a certain date (30.09.2019) is.

my `selectInput` looks like:

```
selectInput(inputId = 'date',
            label = 'Stichtag:',
            choices = sub("([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})", "\\3.\\2.\\1",sort(as.Date(
 sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})KRB.csv", "\\1.\\2.\\3",
 list.files('./data', full.names = FALSE,
 recursive = FALSE)),format="%d.%m.%Y"),decreasing = T)
   )),
```

and my `conditionalPanel`

```
conditionalPanel(
     #condition = " input.date == '30.09.2019'",  #(this works)                        
     condition="Date.parse(input.date)>Date.parse(30.08.2019)", #(it dose not work)
     ## select the variables and order
               pickerInput(
                   inputId = "assetclass",
                   label = "Assetklassen:",
                   choices = c(sort(unique(bestand.name))),    
                   sort(unique(bestand.name)),  
                   multiple = T
               ) ),
```

in the code above you see 2 conditions. The first one

```
 condition = " input.date == '30.09.2019'"
```

works but is not the general smart solution because I will every 3 months I will have an additional date.
Therefore I am looking for a general solution like

```
condition="Date.parse(input.date)>Date.parse(30.08.2019)"
```

I know that I have to use `Js`. But it dose not work!

Addendum: I tried to see the format of the input date in `server.R`

```
Browse[2]> input$date
[1] "30.09.2019"
```

so I have probably to transforme the strings in dates befor I compare them in `JS`!?
I tried just for fun the following statement:

```
 condition= "new Date('2013-05-23') > new Date('2013-05-24')",
```

however, it dose not work!

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of trouble if you use `renderUI` instead of `conditionalPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are asking about how to compare dates in `conditionalPanel`, but whatever you are trying to do, it will be much easier using `renderUI` on the server side.

From your question I assume that you have some quarterly reports running and that with the changes of the quarter you want to display different filters / selectInputs.

Below I show a toy example which checks if the chosen `input$date` is equal to end date of last quarter (`round_date(Sys.Date(), "quarter") - days(1))`).

Note, that I added library calls to `stringr` and `lubridate`.

I further made up a character vector of csv files names, since I cannot reproduce the code you provide.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("lubridate")
library("stringr")

# made up character vector of csv file names
date_vec <- c("30092019KRB.csv",
              "31082019KRB.csv",
              "31072019KRB.csv",
              "30062019KRB.csv",
              "31052019KRB.csv",
              "30042019KRB.csv")

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage( # user interface

    sidebarLayout( # layout with Sidebar

      sidebarPanel( # input sidebarPanel

        selectInput(inputId = 'date',
                    label = 'Stichtag:',
                    choices = sub("([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})",
                                  "\\3.\\2.\\1",
                                  sort(as.Date(sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})KRB.csv",
                                                   "\\1.\\2.\\3",
                                       # below date_vec replaces your list.files() call
                                                   date_vec), 
                                               format="%d.%m.%Y"),
                                       decreasing = T)
                    )
        ) ,

        uiOutput("classes")

      ), # closes sidebarPanel

      mainPanel( # Output in mainPabel


      ) # closes mainPanel

    ) # closes sidebarLayout

  ), # closes fluidPage

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$classes <- renderUI({

      # example condition: if input$date is equal to the date of the actual quarter minus 1 day then...
      if(dmy(str_remove(input$date, "KRB.csv")) == (round_date(Sys.Date(), "quarter") - days(1))) {

      # use show this pickerInput ....
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "assetclass",
        label = "Assetklassen:",
        choices = c("class a", "class b", "class c"),
        multiple = T
      )

      # otherwise show this pickerInput ...
      } else {

        pickerInput(
          inputId = "equity",
          label = "Equity classes:",
          choices = c("class d", "class e", "class f"),
          multiple = T
        )  

      }

    })


  }

) # closes shinyApp
```

If you prefer `conditionalPanel` you can build on the approach from Udit (below), but instead writing a JS function you could bring your input vector into the right format and use it as is.

However, if you use the input vector later on the server side you would need to bring it into the old format with some string manipulation.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

# made up character vector of csv file names
date_vec <- c("30092019KRB.csv",
              "31082019KRB.csv",
              "31072019KRB.csv",
              "30062019KRB.csv",
              "31052019KRB.csv",
              "30042019KRB.csv")

choice_vec <- gsub("[-]",
                   "/",
                   sort(as.Date(sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})KRB.csv",
                                    "\\3.\\2.\\1",
                                    # below date_vec replaces your list.files() call
                                    date_vec), 
                                format="%Y.%m.%d"),
                        decreasing = T)
)



names(choice_vec) <- sub("([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})",
                         "\\3.\\2.\\1",
                         sort(as.Date(sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})KRB.csv",
                                          "\\1.\\2.\\3",
                                          # below date_vec replaces your list.files() call
                                          date_vec), 
                                      format="%d.%m.%Y"),
                              decreasing = T)
)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage( # user interface

    sidebarLayout( # layout with Sidebar

      sidebarPanel( # input sidebarPanel

        selectInput(inputId = 'date',
                    label = 'Stichtag:',
                    choices = choice_vec
        ) ,

        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "new Date('2019/09/30') > new Date(input.date)",
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "assetclass",
            label = "Asset casses:",
            choices = c("class a", "class b", "class c"),
            multiple = T
          )
        )

      ), # closes sidebarPanel

      mainPanel( # Output in mainPabel

      ) # closes mainPanel

    ) # closes sidebarLayout

  ), # closes fluidPage

  server = function(input, output) {



  }

) # closes shinyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can convert your date to a valid date, you might consider making a function out of it:

```
var date = "30.09.2019"
var arr = date.split(".")

var array = Array.from(arr);
array.reverse();
array.join("/"); // this will return a valid date
```

Try Comparing like following

```
new Date(input.date) > new Date("2019/09/30")
```

following is the function which would give you converted Date

```
function convertDate(data){
var arr = data.split(".")

var array = Array.from(arr);
var converted = array.reverse().join("/")

return converted;
}
```

Now where you are comparing just use you normal comparison method

```
  new Date() > new Date(convertDate("30.09.2019"))
```

and it will return if it is true or not.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: It dose not work because of the format, as you mentioned correctly. I add an addendum in the question.

Comment: I probably have to do it, But how?

Comment: I have updated the answer, Please mark as solution if it helps.

Comment: condition= "new Date('2019/09/30') >  new Date('2019/08/30')",   works! Now, how can I build the trensormation part in my ur.R so that input.date is transformed in the correct format?

Comment: Thats what i said. Create a function out of the above code and pass input.date like, convertDate(input.date) so that it will convert and return converted date. If you have problem with this i will update the code.